# about responsive search bar and select box

Tags: css, responsive-design

I couldn't edit the searchbox here. When I switch to the mobile version, how can I create a search icon like on the IMDb website and cover the entire header with a searchbar? and also I need select box with searchbar on mobile. I need help. thank you.

I couldn't reach any conclusion. I am waiting for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<style>
    .navbar-dark .nav-item .nav-link {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none; /* Link altı çizgisini kaldırma */
    }

    .navbar-dark .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .fa-li {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .custom-container {
        padding-left: 15px; /* Tarayıcı sınırından 5 piksel sağa kaydırma */
        padding-right: 15px; /* Tarayıcı sınırından 5 piksel sola kaydırma */
    }

    /* Mega menü stilleri */
    .mega-menu {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #343a40;
        display: none;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .mega-menu .row {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .mega-menu .col {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    .menu-container {
        border: 1px solid #555; /* Koyu renkli çerçeve */
        border-radius: 5px; /* Kenar yuvarlaklığı */
        padding: 10px; /* İçerik boşluğu */
        transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Geçiş efekti */
        
    }

    .menu-container:hover {
        border-color: #868686; /* Hover durumunda çerçeve rengi */
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(16, 15, 15, 0.375), inset 0 0 10px rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.375); /* Dış ve iç gölgelendirme */
    }

    .mega-menu .menu-title {
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .mega-menu .menu-description {
        color: #ccc;
        margin-bottom: 5px; /* Boşluk azaltıldı */
        font-size: 14px; /* Açıklama metni font boyutu küçültüldü */
    }

    .mega-menu .menu-item {
        color: #ccc;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        font-size: 15px; /* Alt menü font boyutu */
    }

    .mega-menu .menu-item a {
        display: block; /* Itemleri blok element yaparak alt alta yerleştirme */
        text-decoration: none; /* Link altı çizgisini kaldırma */
        color: #ccc; /* Link rengi */
    }

    .mega-menu .menu-item a:hover {
        color: #fff; /* Hover durumunda link rengi */
    }

    /* FontAwesome icon styling */
    .fa-custom {
        margin-right: 5px; /* İkon ve metin arası boşluk */
    }

    /* Hover effect for menu items */
    .menu-item {
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .menu-item:hover {
        background-color: rgba(245, 241, 241, 0.1);
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
    }
</style>
<body>

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <!-- Container wrapper -->
        <div class="container-fluid custom-container"> <!-- custom-container sınıfı ekledik -->
            <!-- Navbar brand -->
            <a class="navbar-brand me-0" href="#"><img id="MDB-logo"
                    src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/logo-mdb-jquery-small.png" alt="MDB Logo"
                    draggable="false" height="30" /></a>

            <!-- Toggle button -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>

            <!-- Collapsible wrapper -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <!-- Left links -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-3">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active d-flex align-items-center" aria-current="page" href="#"><i
                                class="fas fa-bars pe-2"></i>Menu</a>
                        <div class="mega-menu">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <!-- Category 1 -->
                                        <div class="menu-container">
                                            <div class="menu-title">Category 1</div>
                                            <div class="menu-description">Description 1</div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-star fa-custom"></i> Item 1</a></div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-star fa-custom"></i> Item 2</a></div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-star fa-custom"></i> Item 3</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <!-- Category 2 -->
                                        <div class="menu-container">
                                            <div class="menu-title">Category 2</div>
                                            <div class="menu-description">Description 2</div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-custom"></i> Item 1</a></div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-custom"></i> Item 2</a></div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-custom"></i> Item 3</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <!-- Category 3 -->
                                        <div class="menu-container">
                                            <div class="menu-title">Category 3</div>
                                            <div class="menu-description">Description 3</div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-custom"></i> Item 1</a></div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-custom"></i> Item 2</a></div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-custom"></i> Item 3</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <!-- Category 4 -->
                                        <div class="menu-container">
                                            <div class="menu-title">Category 4</div>
                                            <div class="menu-description">Description 4</div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment fa-custom"></i> Item 1</a></div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment fa-custom"></i> Item 2</a></div>
                                            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comment fa-custom"></i> Item 3</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Left links -->

                <form class="d-flex align-items-center w-100 form-search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle shadow-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-expanded="false" style="padding-bottom: 0.4rem;">
                            All
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark fa-ul">
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="fa-li pe-2"><i
                                            class="fas fa-search"></i></span>All</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="fa-li pe-2"><i
                                            class="fas fa-film"></i></span>Titles</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="fa-li pe-2"><i
                                            class="fas fa-tv"></i></span>TV
                                    Episodes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="fa-li pe-2"><i
                                            class="fas fa-user-friends"></i></span>Celebs</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="fa-li pe-2"><i
                                            class="fas fa-building"></i></span>Companies</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="fa-li pe-2"><i
                                            class="fas fa-key"></i></span>Keywords</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="fa-li pe-2"><i
                                            class="fas fa-search-plus"></i></span>Advanced
                                    search<i class="fas fa-chevron-right ps-2"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                    </div>
                    <a href="#!" class="text-white"><i class="fas fa-search ps-3"></i></a>
                </form>

                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-3">
                    <li class="nav-item me-3">
                        <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#!">IMDbPro</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center me-3" href="#!">
                            <i class="fas fa-bookmark pe-2"></i> Watchlist
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" style="width: 65px;">
                        <a class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#!">Sign In</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Collapsible wrapper -->
        </div>
        <!-- Container wrapper -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Navbar -->

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            const megaMenu = document.querySelector(".mega-menu");
            const menuToggle = document.querySelector(".nav-link.active");
            let isMegaMenuOpen = false;

            menuToggle.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (!isMegaMenuOpen) {
                    megaMenu.style.display = "block";
                    isMegaMenuOpen = true;
                } else {
                    megaMenu.style.display = "none";
                    isMegaMenuOpen = false;
                }
            });

            document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                const targetElement = event.target;
                if (!targetElement.matches(".nav-link.active") && !targetElement.closest(".mega-menu")) {
                    megaMenu.style.display = "none";
                    isMegaMenuOpen = false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.